# How to change a value of a "Value" service?

Tags: angularjs

I created an injectable value used in the entire application. Recently, I want to change it value. Here is the simulation of my situation:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']) // Create a value
    .value('myValue','foo');


angular.module('app')
    .controller('firstCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', 'myValue', function($scope, $filter, myValue){
        myValue = 'bar';
        console.log(myValue); // bar
    }])
    .controller('secondCtrl', ['myValue', function(myValue){
        console.log(myValue); // foo
    }]);
```

However, the value of `myValue` didn't change at all, as you can see in the `secondCtrl`. How can I change this value? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: In JavaScript, strings are immutable and a primitive. It is not possible to do what you are asking. See sylwester's answer for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google 'angular dot rule', and you've got twice defined app module.

Please see demo below.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app') // Create a value
  .value('myValue', {
    data: 0
  });

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, myValue) {


  $scope.value = myValue;

  $scope.update = function() {

    myValue.data = 8;

  }

});

app.controller('secondCtrl', function($scope, myValue) {

  $scope.value = myValue;


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">

      <button ng-click="update()">update</button>
      <br/>home: {{value.data}}

    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div ng-controller="secondCtrl">
      second: {{value.data}}

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have done as you did before. However, I prefer to find a way to use String rather than Object.